How to copy/rsync? old home folder from a full timeshift snapshot with original dates? possible? how?
I have done one (whole disk, including home folder, even root folder) timeshift snapshot yesterday quickly, expecting an SSD failure soon.
Well I did not expect it so soon, it happened today, SSD unresponsive.
Is it please possible to somehow copy or rsync or whatever,.. the old home folder with keeping the original dates? If so, how?
Thank you kindly in any case, not answering comments of type "timeshift is not backup" because I did not have time for a full disk image backup yesterday, and it happened so quick :(( Thanks again. I will review answers in the morning.
Comments section:
@1.Kusalananda:
timeshift-gtk is a part of Linux Mint for ages, but I believe timeshift command-line is available to other distros without the GTK frontend. I honestly do not know the inner workings of it. And sadly I myself never used rsync at all on my own. Additionaly, I made a screenshot of one folder in the timeshifted "backup" - it has its original date:

@2.ChrisDavies:
alias ls='\ls --color=auto --group-directories-first --time-style=+'\''%Y-%b-%d'\'''
alias ll='ls -lhk'

vlastimil@dell-7577:/media/vlastimil/Seagate_5TB_Ext4/timeshift/snapshots/2024-08-27_09-12-32/localhost/home/vlastimil$ ll
total 1,4G
drwxrwxr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  8-ball
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Jan-24  adamek
drwxrwxr-x  5 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Feb-15  ads-google--overeni
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  alza-ram--jirka
drwxrwxr-x  5 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Jan-30  alza-reklamace-hdd
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  ancestry
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Mar-27  android-vykonny-rezim
drwxr-xr-x  8 root      root       4,0K 2024-Jul-08  apache2
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2021-Sep-12  arbitr
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  asus--eye-care-plus--monitor
drwxrwxr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-14  audioknihy
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2021-Nov-05  aukro-obtezovani
drwxrwxr-x  4 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Nov-01  aukro-prodej
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  aukro-ramecek
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  bazos-autobaterie
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-10  bmnet.cz--isp
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Aug-04  burdik-oblekovice
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Jun-11  burian.work
drwxrwxr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Jul-29  centropol
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-May-01  chrome-remote-desktop
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  ClamAV
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Jun-21  cleanity-pro
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Jan-06  coi--icell
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Mar-10  corsair-flashky
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2021-Jun-07  covid-samotesty
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-May-03  cs-george-otec
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Oct-07  csharp-codepage
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Feb-12 'czc-ssd-reklamace Patriot Burst Elite 120GB'
drwxrwxr-x 18 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Aug-26  Data
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-19  datahelp-eko-likvidace-hdd
drwxrwxrwx  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-10  ddrescue-logs
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  dell-NTB
drwxr-xr-x  4 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Aug-29  Desktop
drwxr-xr-x  9 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2021-Jan-17  Development
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Feb-08  disks-backup
drwxrwxr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Feb-19  disky
drwxrwxr-x  5 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Aug-25  DMARC
drwxrwxr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  DNS
drwxr-xr-x 33 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Aug-26  Documents
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-28  donio
drwxrwxr-x 11 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Jul-19  donio-platby
drwxrwxr-x  5 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-13  Dopamine-Forerunners-remix
drwxr-xr-x 31 vlastimil vlastimil   12K 2024-Aug-26  Downloads
drwxrwxrwx  7 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2019-Mar-30  DPFO_2018
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2020-Mar-18  DPFO_2019
drwxrwxr-x 15 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Mar-21  DPFO_2022
drwxrwxr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Apr-25  DPFO_2023
drwxrwxr-x  5 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-30  DPFO_2023_podklady
drwxrwxr-x  5 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  easydmarc-analysis
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-24 'EEE (Energy Efficient Ethernet)'
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Apr-24  elektrina-2023
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Jun-20  encefalitida-ockovani
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-13  fakturaonline-cz
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-11  fcb-servis-spam-recenze
drwx---rwx  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Mar-18  FiraxisLive
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2019-Oct-15  flash-32
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil   12K 2024-Aug-03  FoE
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Aug-24  generali-cp--mamka
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Oct-19  github_images
drwx------  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2020-Jun-27  GPUCache
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-13  hdd-datahelp--vykup
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  hedepy
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  hello-bank
drwxrwxr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Aug-26  hesla
drwxr-xr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Jul-05  honza
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Jul-27  honza-ext-8tb
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Jan-08  honza-mys-czc
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-13  icmp6
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-26  invalidni-duchod
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-22  iptables
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-May-30  kania.info
drwxrwxr-x  6 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-18  kontrola-zivnosti
drwxrwxr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Nov-12  krbylevne-ancona
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Jan-12  krizovky-mail-spam
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-May-06  kucinovi-ps4pro
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2020-Sep-14  kulecnik-z-fcb
drwxrwxr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  lekarske-zpravy
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Oct-09  lida-pohreb
drwxr-xr-x  6 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2019-Nov-17  mailboxes
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-May-31  mailvelope
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2021-Jan-25  mall--flashka--podvod
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-May-04  mamka-duchod
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-07  mamka-lenovo
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  mamka-OP
drwxr-xr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-13  mdisc
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  mikrovlnka
drwxrwxr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2019-Oct-25  MissYou
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-13  moje-videa
drwxr-xr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  moje-videa2
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-13  moneta-vypisy
drwxrwxr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-19  monitory-prodej
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Oct-05  Mutumutu
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Jan-31  naturamed
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2021-Jun-07  nod32
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  novy-OP
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Jun-13  o2-300kc-sleva
drwxrwxrwx  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-23  o2-pods
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-25  o2-pods--sluchatka
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Jul-20  odkazy
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  odklad-splatek-2024
drwxrwxr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-22  odorik
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-May-01  office2021
drwxrwxr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Mar-07  openssl-enc
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2020-Jun-08  openwrt-ipv6
drwxrwxr-x  4 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-23  osobni-skore
drwxrwxr-x  4 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Aug-20  pes
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Jun-26  pic-kulecnik
drwxr-xr-x 32 vlastimil vlastimil   12K 2024-Jul-10  Pictures
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  pigz
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Jul-10  ping-test--2024-jul-10
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2021-Mar-23  pracka-romo
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-22  preneseni-win10
drwxrwxr-x 10 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-13  programyburian.cz
drwxrwxr-x  5 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-04  proton
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Jul-03  ps4-pro
drwxr-xr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Aug-25  PycharmProjects
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Jul-20  Questions_and_Answers
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  raspberry
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Feb-18  reallysimple-ssl
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2021-Mar-23  recuva
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-23  redshift
drwxrwxr-x  6 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Apr-25  routery
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-14  samoodecet-elektriny
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  sencor-vysavac--reklamace-mall
drwxrwxr-x  9 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-22  servispc-burian
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Jan-03  seznam-firma
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  skylink
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-30  slavia-pojistka
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Feb-27  smaty-sd-karta-rekl
drwx------  6 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Jul-04  snap
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  ssd-lexar
drwxrwxr-x  4 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Jun-24  ssd-prodej
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2021-Dec-10  ssd-vadny
drwxrwxr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Jul-14  switch-prodej
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Jun-02  SynologySync
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-May-15  szn-profi
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2020-Mar-27  tago
drwxrwxr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-24  tar-hidden-test
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2020-Sep-29  telefon-novy
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Jun-20  tgi
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Sep-16  timeshift-archives
drwxrwxr-x  4 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2020-Aug-14  tmp
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Aug-26  torrent-uploads
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Jun-15  touchpad-navrkalova
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Feb-14  ubuntu-pro
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Aug-03  uniqa-vypoved
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-05  unix_and_linux
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Jan-27  vadny-hdd-mironet
drwxrwxr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  vim-syntax-sh
drwxrwxr-x  3 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Aug-26  virtualbox-vms
drwxrwxr-x 10 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Dec-13  vlastimilburian.cz
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Sep-01  Vodafone
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Jun-17  vorwerk-vk135
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Aug-22  vydaje-2024
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Mar-22  vypadek-elektriky
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Jan-11  vysoke-energie
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-26  vzp--ochranny-limit
drwxrwxr-x  4 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  Win11-burnISO
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  wobenzym
drwxrwxr-x  4 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2024-Apr-08  work
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2021-Oct-17  wpa3-vs-wpa2
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2023-Jan-15  xiaomi-redmi
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Jun-20  zonky-ja-2022
drwxrwxr-x  2 vlastimil vlastimil  4,0K 2022-Jun-18  zonky-otec
-rw-r--r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   42M 2019-Jul-24  0-interni-data_2019-03-30.tar.xz.enc
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  190K 2020-Nov-29  100fp-for-50k.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   50K 2020-Nov-23  100fps-ad-price16k.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  1,2M 2021-Jun-01  100k-fragmentu-hdd.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  351K 2020-Feb-19  122132448Z.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  445K 2020-Mar-12  2019-nCoV-CDC-23312_without_background.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  1,6M 2021-Aug-08  2021-08-08_12-42.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  114K 2021-Aug-17  2021-08-17_18-23.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  343K 2021-Sep-09  2021-09-09_15-57.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  1,8M 2021-Oct-02  20211002132338_1.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   27K 2024-Mar-17  2024-03-17_21-15.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   40K 2021-Jun-25  21546815.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  182K 2023-Nov-02  249149001_10224307496493712_9126985411795083171_n.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   65K 2020-Jul-30  256color_chart.svg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  261K 2020-Dec-08  2k-fps-in-stash.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   40K 2022-Sep-30  37_year_old_birthday_cake_postcard.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   56K 2023-Oct-04  4019238791624.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   81K 2024-Aug-25  455820023_1040374308091060_2697680341966188384_n.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  175K 2024-Aug-25  456848896_460640406958320_2635136546288189181_n.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   863 2023-Jul-05  486--fcb--popis
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  361K 2023-Oct-24  489990480.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  189K 2020-Oct-25  4k-brave-playback--HW.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   93K 2024-Feb-21  4tis-monca--vysmech.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   39K 2023-Jul-18  5-hvezdickova-recenze.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   29K 2022-Oct-23  5_odpoved23-10_spotrebitele-na-vyjadreni-TGI-advokatem-dorucene19-10-2022.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  117K 2019-May-27  6190127671.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   16K 2024-Jun-24  8TB-.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   340 2019-Apr-16  90percent-thread
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  2,0M 2023-Aug-07  A-Brief-History-of-Time.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    58 2021-Jan-02  acer-adapter-rozmery
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  5,7M 2021-May-01  adamek-doma.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   704 2021-May-27  adamek--ztracen--text
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  7,4K 2020-Feb-22  adblock.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   81K 2020-Nov-12  ads100k.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   448 2022-Feb-24  ads-google-refund
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  105K 2022-Feb-24  ads-google-refund.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   200 2024-Jan-30  AF-goods.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    23 2023-Dec-13  airbank-heslo.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  8,9K 2021-Mar-26  aktivacni-autorizacni--kod--samotesty.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil     5 2023-Aug-22  aktivacni-kod-starnet.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  894K 2021-Jun-22  all-season-contact.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   189 2020-Nov-10  alpirossl-secured--html
-rw-------  1 vlastimil vlastimil  354K 2024-May-20  alza-plus.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   51K 2020-Mar-20  aramith-duramith.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  138K 2020-Jul-20  arc-68.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   88K 2020-Nov-23  arc80finished--list-of-gbs.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   253 2020-Nov-12  arc-forecast-80
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  8,2M 2023-Mar-30  ASUS_VY249HE_UM-English.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  176K 2023-Jul-19  aukro-atx-zdroj-350w-s-molexem--platba.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   340 2022-Feb-21  badblocks1
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   514 2021-Sep-21  balajka-hodnoceni
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   547 2021-Sep-22  balajka-hodnoceni-mama
-rw-r--r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  3,8K 2024-Jun-25  bashrc-new.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   40K 2021-Apr-22  bashrc-titlebar-not-working.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   178 2020-Jan-24  baterie-format
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   48K 2023-Nov-03  best-url-shorteners.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   545 2023-Mar-10  big-bang-theory--prodej
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  254K 2023-Jan-31  bios-vmd-controller2.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   73K 2023-Jan-31  bios-vmd-controller.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  185K 2024-Jul-02  bitdef-central.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   341 2020-Jun-27  black-orchid--GBG
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    10 2019-Jul-27  boovie
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  114K 2020-Oct-15  brave-logo.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  174K 2023-Aug-06  brave-stats--1mil.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   54K 2020-Nov-07  brave-stats--60minutes.jpg
-rw-rw-rw-  1 vlastimil vlastimil   153 2020-Oct-17 'brave-sync (copy).txt'
-rw-rw-rw-  1 vlastimil vlastimil   159 2024-Aug-29  brave-sync.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    21 2023-Sep-10  brintellix-20mg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  5,8M 2023-Apr-23 'Brožura Jak předcházet vzniku kýly.pdf'
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   327 2023-Mar-12  bruce--breaking-rules
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    23 2024-Apr-26  bryle-titanflex.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   142 2021-Sep-30  btrfs-try-1
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  244K 2023-Dec-26  burdik-hdd--diag.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   96K 2020-Oct-25  buriancouk--expire.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  300K 2023-Apr-27  burian-elektrina.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   64K 2023-Apr-13  burian-router--ping-wan-allowed.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   59K 2023-Oct-23  bye.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   73K 2023-Sep-14  call-spam.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  199K 2020-Nov-16  cape10.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   46K 2023-Feb-16  capslock--mint.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  536K 2024-Jun-21  caution--you-are-being-monitored.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   42K 2020-Oct-25  celluloid-hwaccel.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  289K 2022-Feb-07  centropol-fa2021.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  2,8K 2024-Apr-13  certbot-log.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   623 2021-May-14  ce-trade-offer
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  134K 2021-May-12  cez-nabidka-elektriny.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  1,2K 2024-Apr-13  chkrootkit-suspicious-files.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    18 2023-Oct-16  cholesterol.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  338K 2022-Dec-25  chranene-bydleni-brno.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  360K 2023-Dec-02  chromecka--alza-ssd-1tb--493748274.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  351K 2020-Oct-17  cinsky-koronavirus.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil     5 2020-Dec-23  cislo-dotazu-1212
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  276K 2021-May-07  citroen--zelena-karta--od-23-7-2021.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   137 2024-Feb-07  cleo--lost-fps.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  496K 2023-Dec-08  cmos-baterie-x2--alza-2942543200.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   56K 2020-Oct-25  cold-vs-flu-vs-corona.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   77K 2021-Mar-06  computer-sleep-.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   49K 2021-Mar-06  computer-sleep.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   87K 2021-Jul-13  Confirmation_of_payment.PDF
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   93K 2022-Jul-12  congratulations-jirka.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   73K 2023-Oct-04  continental--allseasoncontact--eu-rating.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   99K 2020-Mar-21  covid19-myth--cold-snow.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    13 2022-Oct-05  covid--4ta-davka--moje
-rw-------  1 vlastimil vlastimil   35K 2021-May-03  covid-terminy.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   57K 2022-Feb-04  cpost-mamka-zmena30kc.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  466K 2020-Jan-09  cpp__always_inline_performance.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    49 2021-Jul-05  cron-test
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    16 2024-Apr-29  cs-business-ucet.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    30 2024-Apr-24  cs-business-virtualka.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    66 2022-Jun-21  cs-pujcka-urok
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil     9 2022-Dec-27  cssz-id
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    34 2024-Jul-18  cs-ucet.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   195 2022-Jan-12  cs-virtualka
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  124K 2021-Dec-09  cutoff-power.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  111K 2023-Jan-31  cv--vlastimil-burian.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  7,0M 2023-Apr-29  CZ13530_GL503VD_VM_GL703VD_VM_V2_A.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  181K 2021-Jun-25  CZ1608000000004423481043_2000006393105782.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  180K 2022-Jan-11  CZ1608000000004423481043_2000008148009323.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  192K 2022-Feb-24  CZ1608000000004423481043_2000008526335008.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  182K 2022-Jun-13  CZ1608000000004423481043_2000009513006888.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  181K 2023-Feb-22  CZ1608000000004423481043_2000011899033251.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   99K 2021-Dec-07  czc-hodnoceni-nefunguje.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   91K 2020-May-11  czc--Informacni_list_k_pojisteni_EW.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  154K 2020-Apr-04  cznic--domain-vlastimilburian.cz.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  1,1M 2021-Jun-28  CZ_reklamacni_protokol.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  531K 2022-Jun-29  data-recovery-img.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    53 2023-Aug-01  datova-schranka-osobni
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   260 2020-Feb-04  death
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  3,1M 2021-Apr-08  dell-ID-example.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   75K 2023-Jul-05  derflice-Vlasta-sedi-na-posteli.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  389K 2020-Nov-07  devitka2005.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  153K 2023-Sep-15 'D-FIXNE PRO TEBE na 1 rok_EG.D.pdf'
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   117 2018-Nov-05  dhcpv6
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    27 2023-Oct-14  dieta-cholesterol.txt
-rwxr-xr-x  1 vlastimil vlastimil   358 2023-Jun-24  disable-eee
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  294K 2023-Jun-25  dlink-dsg108.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  113K 2020-Oct-25  dmarc-fail.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  114K 2020-Oct-25  dmarc-fail--pokus-o-podvrh-meho-emailu.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   52K 2020-Oct-25  dmarcly--full-pass.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  115K 2020-Oct-25  dmarcly--only-spf-no-dkim-or-dmarc.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   150 2022-Dec-18  dmarc-record--default.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   28K 2020-Oct-25  dmarc-test-gmail.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   80K 2023-Jan-04  DNS-over-HTTPS--chrome.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   56K 2023-Jan-05  DNS-over-HTTPS--test.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  245K 2020-Jun-13  dns-query-speed.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   90K 2020-Apr-06  dnssec.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  153K 2020-Oct-25  dnssec-test.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   130 2021-Jan-31  dns-servis-txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   59K 2022-Jan-03  dodaci_list-2022-01-03-.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  127K 2023-Nov-28 'Dodatek ke smlouvě Otec.pdf'
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   121 2022-Jun-17  doktori-2022
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   424 2023-Sep-09  domov-pro-invalidy.txt
-rw-------  1 vlastimil vlastimil  779K 2023-May-06  donio-smlouva-scan.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   36M 2020-Mar-14 'Don'\''t Trust China, China is Asshoe Remix - Music Video - Age restricted for no reason [hicC53AhZ6Y].webm'
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    37 2023-Jul-12  dpd-kuryr-mamka-kapsicky
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  358K 2022-Mar-21  dpd-odmitnuto.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  292K 2022-Mar-23  dpd-vraceno.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   251 2024-Aug-11  dragons-pieces.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   279 2020-Aug-05  Driver-Booster_serial-number.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  121K 2020-Oct-25  driver-manager--nvidia-450.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   88K 2021-Jun-03  driver-manager--nvidia-465.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  626K 2023-Mar-29  drmax-gingko.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  439K 2023-Dec-24  duchod-2024.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  1,6K 2024-Jun-20  duchod-banka.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   67K 2020-Feb-23  duckduck.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   28K 2020-Feb-23  duckduck.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  2,4M 2020-Jan-16  E5971_M4N68t-m_Series_manual.zip
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   64K 2023-Oct-27  easydmarc.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  6,3K 2023-Oct-27  easydmarc.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   50K 2024-Jun-21  eat-sleep-code-repeat.jpg
-rw-rw-rw-  1 vlastimil vlastimil    75 2019-Dec-23  electrum_wallet_seed
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    75 2023-Oct-16  electrum_wallet_seed_
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    87 2022-Feb-22  elektrina-leden-unor
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  1,1M 2020-Jun-29  elektromer.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  1,4K 2022-Mar-09  emailprofi--seznam--dmarc
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  274K 2022-Jan-12  emos-zarovky--doklad-3roky.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    32 2022-Jan-02  empire-heslo-mama.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   364 2022-Sep-17  EN1-intro
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  205K 2021-Mar-14  endora-emaily-kde-je-smazat.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   70K 2020-Nov-11  endora-timeout.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  128K 2020-Nov-11  endora-vypnoutTLS11.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  136K 2021-Sep-30  eneloop-nabijecka.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    53 2022-Dec-25  english-locale-override
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  117K 2020-Oct-25  eon-distribuce--chyba.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  536K 2022-Jan-12  epojisteni-uniqa-majetek.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   58K 2023-Jul-13  eset--rivalenticz--zachyt.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  702M 2022-Jul-28  eset_sysrescue_live_enu-.iso
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   418 2023-Mar-05  example-check-msg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  7,9K 2021-Jun-22  Export_15674559.xlsx
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   28K 2023-Dec-10  extreme-pro-uhs-i-microsd-64gb.png.webp
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   178 2024-Jul-18  fabia-oznaceni.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  177K 2024-Jul-18  fabia--zelena-karta--2024.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  235K 2020-Feb-19  faktura200142766.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  120K 2022-Jan-04  faktura_210702104.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  359K 2023-Nov-28  faktura_ssd_sembol.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  499K 2024-Feb-17  faktura-zdroj-alza-2946556172.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   109 2021-Sep-23  fall-event--boost
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   87K 2024-Apr-06  faonline-nesparovano-matouci-1.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   67K 2024-Apr-06  faonline-nesparovano-matouci-2.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   19K 2022-Jun-29  faster-pc.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  129K 2020-Dec-07  fcb--chybi-smazat.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  336K 2023-Dec-07  fcb--hasici-pristroj.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   340 2020-Dec-10  fcb-honza
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  366K 2021-Sep-30  fcb-limit-posts.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   716 2020-Feb-27  fcb-omluva--zpravy-komplet-vypnuti
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  214K 2020-Oct-25  fcb-potvrzeni-totoznosti-cz.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  330K 2023-Dec-07  fcb--rozdvojka-shorela.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil  103K 2020-Oct-25  fcb-totoznost-us--cancel.png
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil   141 2021-Dec-11  fcb-vypocet--rovnice
-rw-rw-r--  1 vlastimil vlastimil    62 2020-Jan-22  fenix-patek

...


I've never used timeshift. Does it not allow you to restore saved backups? How does it store backups? Are you at all familiar with rsync?

@Kusalananda I thought about it very quick before bed, and I need only non-dot (not hidden) files and folders back.

It looks like you can use rsync (or cp) directly to copy the files exactly as usual.
This version would copy everything including dot files/directories:
cp -a /path/in/your/backup/to/your/home/directory/ .

The trailing dot tells cp to copy to the current directory.
This version will only copy non-dot files and directories:
cp -a /path/in/your/backup/to/your/home/directory/* .

This version will show you what it would do, but won't copy anything until you remove the --dry-run flag:
rsync --dry-run -rt /path/in/your/backup/to/your/home/directory/ .

In all three cases, if you run these commands as your new user the files and directories they create will be owned by that user. If you run them as root the owner/group of the destination files and directories will match those recorded in the backup. Since you are only interested in recovering files and directories for your own home directory you do not need to run the commands as root.
Overall, my preference would be for the rsync solution because you can try it out without it making any changes
